# Horizontal scroll for VDataTable in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

[image: no scroll bar the contents in the second table going out of the page]

I have a component that displays data with v-data-table, but it's going out of bounds and only viewable on desktops when the zoom is set to 60%.

Here is a link to the problematic component: http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/RICK/MORTY.

You can completely view it if zoomed out enough. I have tried different props but none works

I am referring to the component with the heading `AtomicDex OrderBook`.

The component has a v-data-table displaying current open orders for the pairs on the page.

I want to enable horizontal scrolling and limit the component to the page width (responsive). Here's the code:

```
    <v-toolbar flat dense color="indigo">
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <span class="subheading">AtomicDEX order book</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
      <v-chip
        class="ma-2"
        color="white"
        outlined
        @click="refreshMarket()"
      >
        <v-icon left>mdi-server-plus</v-icon>Refresh
      </v-chip>
    </v-toolbar>
    <div v-if="marketdata.asks">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Asks</v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
              dense
              :sort-by="['price']"
              :sort-desc="[true]"
              :hide-default-footer="true"
              :headers="asksHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.asks"
              :items-per-page="-1"
              height="200px"
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.relamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }"> {{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>

              <!-- For highlighting my orders, TODO need a price:uuid array before grouping by price in AppTraderview   -->
              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}
<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template
                v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.maxvolume+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
              <template
                v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.price*item.maxvolume+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current asks to display.</div>
    <h2 class="pl-3">{{ middlePriceSpreadData.middle }} Middle Price (Spread: {{ middlePriceSpreadData.spread}} %)</h2>

    <div v-if="marketdata.bids">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Bids</v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
               dense
              :sort-by="['price']"
              :sort-desc="[true]"
              hide-default-footer
              disable-pagination
              :headers="bidsHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.bids"
              :items-per-page="-1"
              height="200px"
            >

              <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.baseamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">{{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
              
              <!-- For highlighting my orders, TODO need a price:uuid array before grouping by price in AppTraderview   -->
              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}
<!--
better implementation in parent component
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 
              <template
                v-slot:item.baseamount="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.maxvolume/item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
              <template
                v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.maxvolume+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No current bids to display.</div>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: When I look at your page, it looks like there are two data tables in the card, both with three columns, the first takes up 50% of the width, the second takes up the full width, and both are completely visible on all resolutions. So it is not clear what you are asking. Can you clarify the problem, maybe by attaching an image?

Comment: I am unable to view them though one of the tables go out of bounds and the data is half visible, especially the table headers. Can you attach an image if it is visible? How can I add a horizontal scroll to the table?

Comment: I have added an image check that out.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcSZM.png) is how it looks on my laptop. From your image, I think the issue is the long number in `Price (rel)`. Set a max width on the column (or similar) and it should work.

Comment: What about the pagination how do I disable that have tried a lot of different props

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213614/4883195)